# how to create folder inside s3 bucket - serverless framework

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation, serverless-framework

I don't understand the error when I try to create a folder inside the bucket on my serverless.

The error is: BucketXXXX/image/ already exists

Here's the code:

```
resources:
  Resources:
    BucketUpload:
      Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
      Properties:
        BucketName: ${self:service}-${self:provider.stage}-bucket

    BucketFolder:
      Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
      Properties:
        BucketName: !Join ["", [!Ref BucketUpload, "/image/"]]
```

I need create a folder inside the bucket, is possible do it?

Answer (score 0):

> I need create a folder inside the bucket, is possible do it?

Its not possible, without a [custom resource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-custom-resources.html) that you have to develop for creating those folders.